# Flutter - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, dart, nosuchmethoderror

I'm doing the example in Searchview flutter 
https://github.com/MageshPandian20/Flutter-SearchView
but I wanted to make a change to the **ChildItem** class which has a

**final String name attribute;**

and in my case I have a Product class so I had to modify the code in that sense. 
When I run the application I get the following error :

I/flutter (18897): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building IndexFragment(dirty, state:
I/flutter (18897): _SearchListState#4f3d3):
I/flutter (18897): The method 'map' was called on null.
I/flutter (18897): Receiver: null
I/flutter (18897): Tried calling: map(Closure: (Product) => ChildItem)

I don't understand why I can get that error. In a moment of tests and errors run the application 
in debug mode and everything worked but a little slow because of the way I ran it...
I think I have omitted a small detail but when I run the application I get the error mentioned above.
I hope you can help me. Thank you.

*PS: When running the application in debug mode check that the Product list was not empty as well as the attributes of each item in the list.

My Code:

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphqllapp/data/product_data.dart';
import 'package:graphqllapp/modules/product_presenter.dart';

class IndexFragment extends StatefulWidget {

  IndexFragment({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchListState createState() =>  _SearchListState();

 } 

class _SearchListState extends State<IndexFragment> implements ProductListView
{
  Widget appBarTitle = new Text("Portada", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
  Icon actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final TextEditingController _searchQuery = new TextEditingController();
  List<Product> _list;
  bool isSearching;
  String _searchText = "";
  ProductListPresenter _presenter;

  _SearchListState() {
        _presenter = new ProductListPresenter(this);
        _presenter.loadProducts();

    _searchQuery.addListener(() {
      if (_searchQuery.text.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          isSearching = false;
          _searchText = "";
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          isSearching = true;
          _searchText = _searchQuery.text;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void init() {
    _presenter.loadProducts();  
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
    isSearching = false;    
  }


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
   return new Column(
     children: <Widget>[  new Expanded(
          child:  new  SizedBox(
            child: new Carousel(
                     images: [
                       new ExactAssetImage('images/glutamina.jpg'),
                       new ExactAssetImage('images/frasco1.jpg'),
                       new ExactAssetImage('images/frasco.jpg')]
            )
            ),flex: 2),
            new Expanded(
              child:  new Column(children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(icon: actionIcon, onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              if (this.actionIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
                this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white,);
                this.appBarTitle = new TextField(
                  controller: _searchQuery,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white),
                      hintText: "Search...",
                      hintStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  ),
                );
                _handleSearchStart();
              } else {
                _handleSearchEnd();
              }
            });
          },),new ListView(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
        children: isSearching ? _buildSearchList() : _buildList(),
      )] ),flex : 4)]);      
  }

  List<ChildItem> _buildList() {
    return _list.map((product) => new ChildItem(product)).toList();
  }

  List<ChildItem> _buildSearchList() {
    if (_searchText.isEmpty) {
      return _list.map((product) => new ChildItem(product)).toList();
    } else {
      List<Product> _searchList = List();
      for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
        Product product = _list.elementAt(i);
        if (product.name.toLowerCase().contains(_searchText.toLowerCase())) {
          _searchList.add(product);
        }
      }
      return _searchList.map((product) => new ChildItem(product)).toList();
    }
  }

  void _handleSearchStart() {
    setState(() {
      isSearching = true;
    });
  }

  void _handleSearchEnd() {
    setState(() {
      this.actionIcon = new Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,);
      this.appBarTitle =
      new Text("Search Sample", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),);
      isSearching = false;
      _searchQuery.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  void onLoadProductsError(String msg) {
    // TODO: implement onLoadProductsError
  }

  @override
  void onLoadProductsFinish(List<Product> products) {
    // TODO: implement onLoadProductsFinish
    _list = products;
  }
}

class ChildItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  ChildItem(this.product);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
      leading: new CircleAvatar(
          child: Image.memory(product.mainImage),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      title: new Text(product.name, style : new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        subtitle: new Text(product.description) ,
        isThreeLine: true,
      );
  }
}
```

Product Class:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';

class Product {

 int id;
 String name;
 String description;
 Uint8List mainImage;
 Uint8List firstImage;
 Uint8List secondImage;

 Product({this.id,this.name,this.description,this.mainImage,this.firstImage,this.secondImage});

 Product.fromMap(Map<String,dynamic> map)
 :id = map["id"],
  name = map["name"],
  description = map["description"],
  mainImage = base64.decode(map["main_image"]),
  firstImage = base64.decode(map["first_image"]),
  secondImage = base64.decode(map["second_image"]);  
}
```

MockProductRepository class :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:graphqllapp/data/product_data.dart';

class MockProductRepository implements ProductRepository {

  @override
  Future<List<Product>> fetchProducts() async {
    // TODO: implement fetchUsers
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString("mockdata/data.json");
    var jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    return (jsonResult['products'] as List).map((p)=> Product.fromMap(p)).toList();
  }
}
```

Presenter class:

```
import 'package:graphqllapp/data/product_data.dart';
import 'package:graphqllapp/dependency_injection.dart';

abstract class ProductListView {
  void onLoadProductsFinish(List<Product> users);
  void onLoadProductsError(String msg);
}

class ProductListPresenter {

  ProductListView _view;
  ProductRepository _repository;

  ProductListPresenter(this._view){
    _repository = Injector().productRepository;
  }

  void loadProducts(){
    _repository.fetchProducts()
                .then((v)=>_view.onLoadProductsFinish(v))
                .catchError((onError)=>_view.onLoadProductsError("Error to get users: $onError"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be caused by `_list` being `null` before its initialization is done via `onLoadProductsFinish`. Simply declare your `_list` with an empty (`[]`) list and it should work.

```
List<Product> _list = [];
```

Comment: I tried this solution but when the activity is launched I don't get the elements in the Listview and looking at the example by which I was guided they don't have the list of elements initialized with [].Everything is fixed when I do a first search... and that is not correct if the list has elements.